# Load image from any path with haxe

Tags: haxe, openfl

In OpenFL and in heaps they use a Ref or an Asset folder for the objects and images. But I want to display any picture stored on the computer. Is there a way to do that using the path of the file? I look for a library that allows me to move or even delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

How an image is loaded is going to depend on the library you're using.

- OpenFL has a [`openfl.display.BitmapData.fromFile(path)`](https://api.openfl.org/openfl/display/BitmapData.html?#fromFile) API.
- The Heaps API looks similar, there's [`hxd.BitmapData.fromNative(data)`](https://heaps.io/api/hxd/BitmapData.html#fromNative) (though the argument type depends on the target).

For file manipulation, simply use the `sys` package from the stadand library:

- [`FileSystem.deleteFile(path)`](https://api.haxe.org/sys/FileSystem.html#deleteFile)
- [`FileSystem.rename(path, newPath)`](https://api.haxe.org/sys/FileSystem.html#rename)
- ...